# Why does the test show 'pass' although expectation has failed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

```
import React from 'react';
import CrudApi from '../api/CrudApi'; 
import nock from 'nock';

describe('CrudList Component', () => {

    it('should have users', () => {

        afterEach(() => {
          nock.cleanAll()
        })

        CrudApi.getAll().then(
          data => {expect(data).toHaveLength(9) // this failed
          console.log(data.length) // 10}
        )
    });
});
```

This is my test case, it's supposed to fail because `getAll` returns an array with 10 elements. In my console I'm seeing that the test passed, why is that?

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The test indicates its passing because it is not waiting for the promise to resolve - you need to return the promise in the `it` function:

```
it('should have users', () => {

    afterEach(() => {
      nock.cleanAll()
    })

    return CrudApi.getAll().then(
      data => {expect(data).toHaveLength(9) // this failed
      console.log(data.length) // 10}
    )
});
```